# PHP: For loop to be executed only to show html

Tags: php, html, for-loop

I got a resultset from php, from which I want to display an one time result. It is mix of html and php as follows.

```
foreach ($folder_info as $show) {
    if (isset($show['folder_name']) && ($check == 0)) {
        echo '<div class="alert alert-info">';
        echo 'Note! You could click on a Folder to view the images inside it.';
        echo '</div>';
        echo '<br/>';
    }
}
```

By executing the above loop, I am getting the following:
[image: Two times coming]

and my result set array is like follows:-

```
Array (
    [folder_info] => 
        Array ( 
            [0] => Array ( [folder_id] => 1 )
            [1] => Array ( [folder_id] => 2 )
        )
)
```

Any suggestions on how to improve my coding will also be helpful! I want to show the line only one time.

Comment: So there is no problem you just want improvement ideas? That would be more suited to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: break out of foreach once you find the first result. So that would only display the message once instead for all the elements in $folder_info

Comment: @RamRaider, actually i am getting 2 lines. i want only one time to show it. I modified the question..

Comment: @oh i using the `<br/>` inside the loop, should i use out of loop?

Comment: what exactly do you want? Do you want to print the condition only once?

Comment: @NishantNair, yes yes

Comment: @Keynes your ```if(isset($show['folder_name'])&& ($check==0))``` satisfying each time loop is looping. That's why you are getting 2 lines. According to logic it's working fine. By the way, what is ```$check``` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try out this checking the zeroth element `$key == 0`

```
        foreach($folder_info as $key=>$show){ 
          if(isset($show['folder_name'])&&  ($key == 0))
          {                        
            echo '<div class="alert alert-info">';
            echo 'Note! You could click on a Folder to view the images inside it.';
            echo '</div>';
            echo '<br/>';
           }
            }?>
```

Comment: Severity: Notice Message: Undefined variable: check

Comment: remove that condition from your if loop

Comment: Good Hope it helped you

Answer (score 2):

```
$check = 0; // initialize $check here
foreach($folder_info as $show){

          if(isset($show['folder_name'])&& ($check==0))
          {                        
            echo '<div class="alert alert-info">';
            echo 'Note! You could click on a Folder to view the images inside it.';
            echo '</div>';
            echo '<br/>';
          $check++; //increment the $check here
           }
            }?>
```

1. initialize the $check outside the foreach
2. increment $check++ inside the foreach